# Terminology for the join of a complete graph and the complement of a complete graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

What is the name of this graph $K_m +\overline{K}_n$, where $K_m$ is the complete graph, $\overline{K}_n$ is the complement of $K_n$ and $+$ denotes the join of two graphs?

If someone can help with this terminology it will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it has a name? It seems reasonable to call it a "generalized star graph" (in analogy to the $K_1 + \overline{K_n}$ case) if you can't find anything but need a name for a paper, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A graph that can be partitioned into a clique and an independent set is called a *[split graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_graph)*.  A split graph in which every vertex of the clique is adjacent to every vertex of the independent set (that is, the join of a clique and an independent set) is called a *[complete split graph](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1242.html)*.